# angular routes: testing if a route exists

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm defining some navigation and I want a button to be present if a route is acessible or a permission exists. I have done the permissions bit and that works fine but now I am starting to exclude pages depending on configuration. Ideally I want a directive, something like `route-depend` that takes a path and queries the router to see if it exists, and if it does the permissions.

So I have the following:

```
app.config([ "$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/404", {
        templateUrl : "/pages/404.php"
    }).when("/noauth", {
        templateUrl : "/pages/noauth.php"
    }).when("/home", {
        templateUrl : "/pages/homepage.php"
    }).when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "/pages/about.php",
        permission : "logged-in"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/404"
    });
} ]);
```

I have my navigation link set up (same with buttons)

```
<li data-has-permission="logged-in" >
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setActiveTab('about')">ABOUT</a>
</li>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<li data-route-depend="/newpage">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setActiveTab('newpage')">NEW PAGE</a>
</li>
```

Which in my example would mean the `data-route-depend` would fail (and hide the element as my `has-permission` does) as the route is not defined (other than the otherwise redirect to the 404 page)

I have looked at the documentation for [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), and that doesn't seem to have much. It points to the example for `$route` and that, again doesn't seem to have anything like what I am after.

I have cobbled together this:

```
app.directive('routeDepend', [ "$route", function($route) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (!(typeof attrs.routeDepend == "string")) {
                throw 'route-depend value must be a string'
            }
            var value = attrs.routeDepend.trim();

            function toggleVisibilityBasedOnRoute() {
                logger($route.routes); // Shows as object of objects
                for (var route in $route.routes) {
                    if ($route.routes.hasOwnProperty(route)) {
                        logger(typeof route); // shows as a string??
                        logger(route);
                        logger("Checking '"+attrs.routeDepend+"' against '"+route.originalPath+"'"); // undefined originalPath
                        // check route.permission
                    }
                }
            }

            toggleVisibilityBasedOnRoute();
            scope.$on('permissionsChanged', toggleVisibilityBasedOnRoute);
        }
    };
} ]);
```

But as you can see from the comments, things are not resolving as I'm expecting.

What am I doing wrong, how can I make it do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh plop. My for loop was wrong. It should have read:

```
for (routeName in $route.routes) {
    if ($route.routes.hasOwnProperty(routeName)) {
        route = $route.routes[routeName];
```

Then the rest all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the config part done. Instead of querying route, just use the existing config part to show/hide the link

Based on your config, create a function/service which tells you whether the user is allowed to access the path or not.

Then, call that function in `ng-init` if you want to check it only during page load and then decide the visibility of the link.

OR call it in `ng-if` `ng-show` `ng-hide` in case you want to continuously monitor it.

Comment: I don't think this is answer to this question. He ask how to check if route exists not how how to show/hide based on condition.

Comment: I know, but you he did say "I want a button to be present if a route is accessible or a permission exists."

You already have the config part done. Instead of querying route, just use the existing config part to show/hide the link

Comment: But I want to show an about button if the route /about exists, using ng-if, ng-show or ng-hide needs to check if the route is defined somewhere, that's they bit I'm stuck on, once I get that, then I can check the permissions of the route and it all works as I want. Could you expand on how this is done in the config as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the bit that I am specifically trying to get help with is this bit in your answer: "Based on your config, create a function/service which tells you whether the user is allowed to access the path or not."

Comment: @NigelJohnson, are you giving role based permissions and access to routes?

Comment: Yes, I have permission based visibility which is all good, but I also want to control whether a link/button is visible if the route it points at is a) there, and b) visible based on it's require permission. So I might not want a version of the application to have an "about" page for example, therefore the links to it should not be visible either, and I don't want to go though all the HTML hiding the links. The first step is to check the routes table. Which I tried iterating though, but ultimately don't need to with the object accessing via array syntax.